# Mocking config values when testing a class using spring

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, config

I am trying to test a class like

```
@Controller
public class FailureController {

    @Value("#{configValues.defaultRedirectUrl}")
    private String defaultRedirectUrl;
public FailureController (String defaultRedirectUrl) {
this.defaultRedirectUrl = defaultRedirectUrl;
}
...
```

The problem is that I can't test this class without creating a special constructor for test class (like above), which is eventually to initializes the `defaultRedirectUrl` in `FailureController`.

How can I test it without creating a constructor (that are to be come from spring context) during the test. My main objective is to initialize the values in `FailureController` without a constructor when running a test.

Is it possible in some way that spring context gets loaded during the test and initializes the fields in FailureController
 this is what i have been doing but its not working, `defaultRedirectUrl` remains `null` in `FailureController`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext-test.xml" })
public class FailureControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    FailureController failureController;
```

applicationContext-test.xml

```
...
        <bean id="failureController" class="se.synergica.watchtower.controllers.FailureController">
        </bean>

        <import resource="spring-config-test.xml" />
    </beans>
```

thank you. 
al

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate applicationContext.xml file in your test-classpath (src/test/resources in standard projects). There I would set up a configValues object with dummy values.
Your class under test should also be instanciated in that context.

Then load the test context like this in a junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext-test.xml")
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private AClassToBeTest subject;

    //...perform test on subject
}
```

more on spring testing: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html

Comment: Thank you, I think, i did not understand you well enough... would the  theUrl field in AClassToBeTest get initialized? I guess it will not. Is not @ContextConfiguration for loading the context for tests only i.e. AClassToBeTestTest, not for the class that is being tested i.e.AClassToBeTest? I have edited my question little bit.

Comment: The point is that you have AClassToBeTest instantiated by a test application context. So AClassToBeTest should be defined in applicationContext-test.xml. You inject that instance into your unit test and it should be initialized just like in normal runtime. The only difference from runtime is that you use a different spring context where you could load a different properties file for test values or something like that.

Comment: for some reason, its not working. could you help me plz. i hv edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

These config properties usually come from .properties files - simply use a different properties file (with test values) in the unit test classpath

Comment: by using property file, will the fields in the class that is under test get initialized. and how would my test recognize the properties file as in other answer, the @ContextConfiguration is being used for that (although that did not work for me).

Comment: @ContextConfiguration is about the xml file, which in turn loads a properties file (usually) to get properties from an external location